# 'Material' option does not exist in the 'Select Similar' menu

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

Why is there no *Material* option in the *Select Similar* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) menu?

[image]

When I try with a script, I get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertices don't have material data connected to them, *Faces* do. So you need to change to Face select mode in the *3D View* header and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me :)